# Auto startx before login on FreeBSD

Tags: x11, freebsd, tty, x-server, autologin

This problem is driving me crazy!

I use "/etc/ttys" on FreeBSD to configure the commands that are executed when getty is executed.

This is the relevant line of my config file `/etc/ttys`:

```
ttyv8   "/usr/local/bin/startx" xterm on secure
```

My problem is that, on boot, the current console switches to ttyv8 (working  as expected), then my VirtualBox window resizes (which normally indicates that the X Server is taking control over the graphics output), **but then the X server immediately closes**. FreeBSD tries again 5 times, waits 30 seconds and tries again 5 times, waits 30 seconds, and so on. This is driving me crazy!

However, after logging in on a text console and running `startx` from there, it works completely fine without any problems.
I don't have a `~/.xinitrc` but modified the default xinit file in `/usr/local/etc/X11/xinit` .

When I tried debugging the whole stuff adding a pipe to my tty command:

```
ttyv8   "/usr/local/bin/startx > /tmp/startx.log" xterm on secure
```

the startx.log did not exist. It simply did not work. However, the standard Xorg.0.log gets updated with every try getty makes to start the x server. The Xorg.0.log simply says nothing. Just that it ended successfully after drivers etc. were loaded. It's like my xinitrc would not have been read at all.

**Please notice, that I don't want to use a login manager and that I don't want any auto login mechanism.**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> ttyv8   "/usr/local/bin/startx" xterm on secure
> ```

Close, but wrong.

The manual for `ttys` gives an example of how to do exactly this.  You need to specify your actual X server with a `window=` setting and specify the initial X client to run in the second field of the record:

```
# terminal emulate/window system
ttyv0   "/usr/local/bin/xterm -display :0"      xterm   on window="/usr/local/bin/X :0"
```

Personally, I recommend against using this mechanism of `ttys`, for three reasons:

- The restart behaviour is not pretty, as you have discovered.  In fact, there's almost zero configurability of this as compared to a proper service manager, where one can fairly simply do things like configure environment variables for the X client and server and enable/disable services.
- This isn't really how one does this once one has a desktop manager in the mix.  The *FreeBSD Handbook* shows how to run the various destkop managers via their respective Mewburn `rc` scripts, enabled/disabled by settings in `rc.conf`.  TrueOS replaces this with PCDM, invoked by an OpenRC script.  No `ttys` database entries are involved in either.
- This isn't how one does this under nosh service management, which has service bundles for PCDM and the various desktop managers, and for which one would similarly use a service bundle to start a plain X server and client, both enabled and disabled in the normal way for such service bundles.  No `ttys` database entries involved.

I recommend that you write a Mewburn `rc` script, an OpenRC script, or even a nosh service bundle to run your X server and client.

## Further reading

- [`ttys`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ttys&sektion=5).  *FreeBSD File Formats Manual*.  2014-03-09.
- "[The X Window System](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x11.html)". *The FreeBSD Handbook*.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the following way:

1. On `ttyv0` my user automatically log in.
2. My `~/.login` checks the tty. If it's `ttyv0` will run `startx`.
3. After end of `startx` (close the xorg session) asks about halt/reboot.

Explanations:

**1. Automatically login**: to `/etc/ttys`:

```
ttyv0   "/usr/libexec/getty autologin" xterm   on  secure
```

and to `/etc/gettytab`:

```
autologin::al=MYUSER
```

**2. & 3. Relevant content of `~/.login`**. I'm using `tcsh` but the idea works on `sh` too:

```
if ($tty == "ttyv0") then
  echo Starting Xorg...
  startx
  echo "Halt (h) Reboot (r) Nothing (n) ?"
  set answer = $<
  if ($answer == "h") then
    /sbin/shutdown -p now
  else if ($answer == "r") then
    /sbin/shutdown -r now
  endif
endif
```

Comment: The questioner said that xe did not want an automatic login way of doing this.  Xe is trying to get `ttys` to do this, as the manual page for `ttys` says that it can be done.

Comment: Maybe you've right. I thought xe doesn't wants autologin with DM.